# What are limits and pricing for PubSubHubbub google?

Tags: websub

Want use https://pubsubhubbub.appspot.com/ for rss feeds, but can't find limitations or pricing about it. For example how many subscriptions allowed and how fast message about updating. Can any help?

Can't find enough information about this limitations/quotas/price pubsubhubbub google. Dont sure this is completely free